# Running multiple Flink programs in a Flink Standalone Cluster (v1.4.2)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Standalone Cluster based on Flink 1.4.2 (1 job manager, 4 task slots) and want to submit two different Flink programs. 
Not sure if this is possible at all as some flink archives say that a job manager can only run one job. If this is true, any ideas how can I get around this issue? There is only one machine available for the Flink cluster and we don't want to use any resource manager such as Mesos or Yarn.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The Flink jobs (programs) run in task slots which are located in a task manager. Assuming you have 4 task slots, you can run up-to 4 Flink programs. Also, be careful with the parallelism of your Flink jobs. If you have set the parallelism to 2 in both jobs, then yes 2 is the maximum number of jobs you can run on 4 task slots. Each parallel instance runs on a task slot.

Check this image: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/fig/slots_parallelism.svg

Comment: Hi @Alex. Thanks for the clarification. Suppose I have a TM with 4 slots and I deploy a flink job with parallelism=4. Each parallel instance will be deployed in one task slot each (I have the entire job pipeline running per slot). My jobs do a join and they buffer last 3 hours of data. As per Flink docs `the separate threads running in different task slot share data sets and data structures, thus reducing the per-task overhead`. My question is will these threads running in different task slot share this data buffered for join.